# When can I use Hahn-Banach theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given a smooth function $v$ with compact support, we could define a linear functional $f: C_c^1(\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R$
$$f(u) = \int v' u'$$
and we see that $f$ is continuous with respect to the $L^2$ norm
$$|f(u)| = \left|\int v' u'\right| = \left|-\int v'' u\right|\leq \int|v'' u| \leq \|v''\|_2 \|u\|_2$$
Since $C_c^1(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, we know there exists a continuous extension $\hat f : L^2(\mathbb R) \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

I was wondering is there a way to know what $\hat f$ would look like outside of $C_c^1(\mathbb R)$.

Another kind of extension is  $\bar f : L^2(\mathbb R) \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$
$$\bar f(u) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
     f(u) & \quad \text{if } u\in C_c^1(\mathbb R)\\
     + \infty & \quad \text{otherwise}\\
   \end{array} \right. $$

Is there any advantage of using $\bar f$ rather than $\hat f$?

Comment: The point of extending a function(al) by continuity is that it "looks" exactly the same on the extended domain as on the original domain.  For example, if you choose a sequence $(u_n^{\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})})$ that converges to a Heaviside step function, then $u'$ converges to a delta function, and the linear extension of your functional handles this just as it should: the limit looks like the integral $\int v' \delta$.  Your other extension $\bar{f}$ doesn't get this right: it just gives up and calls the limit $\infty$.

Comment: @Sesquipedal Thank you for the reply!

Comment: If we relax the condition to be fixing a $v\in H^2(\mathbb R)$ instead of test functions,  then there might be a problem of summibility for the integral $\int v' u'$ for $u$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension $\tilde f$ you mention is no longer continuous. The continuous extension $\hat f$ you define is in fact unique, which you can show fairly easily.

Usually when you extend a bounded linear map by continuity, you lose the ability to give a precise description of the map. In this case you could describe $\hat f$ in terms of limits and convolutions but I don't see any particular advantage.

Indeed, even in much simpler cases an extension by continuity can remove the ability to simply describe the function. Consider a fixed real number $\alpha>0$ and the function $f(x)=\alpha^x$. If $f$ is defined on $\mathbb Q$ then we have an explicit description (i.e. $f(\frac mn)$ is the unique positive number $y$ such that $y^n=\alpha^m$) but we lose this description once we extend the definition of $f$ by continuity to all real numbers.